# Flexdashboard slow when opening SQLite connection

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, flexdashboard

I want to create a flexdashboard that will show data from a large (5Gb) SQLite database. I placed JUST the `DBI::dbConnect` in an R chunk in order to establish the connection but I'm not retrieving any data at this step. With this, the dashboard takes 30 second to start. If I remove the `DBI::dbConnect`, the dashboard starts in a couple of seconds.

Connecting to the database in R Console, with `con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = my_large_db.sqlite)` also takes less than a second.

Why is it so slow when doing it in a flexdashboard chunk? Any suggestions on how to speed things up? In the future, I plan on moving the data to a PostgreSQL server. But for now I'm using SQLite.

Thanks

Comment: Just found out that the dashboard loads quickly if I use a small SQLite database. Funny that I'm only opening the conection. I'm not retrieving any data from the DB. Does the shiny app scans the entire database when I connect, even though I don't read anything from it?

Comment: Also tested with postgreSQL. Flexdashboard starts almost instantly. So probably there is something going on with SQLite connection